# Script to convert Customer Record to Invoice on a link or button click in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Our company is brand new with Netsuite and I am dabbling in basic scripting.
I have very little programming background, but I am hoping to start learning and testing by creating simple scripts to automate basic tasks.

The first one I want to try is this:
We have a payment system integrated into Netsuite and the payment system can be activated on a Sales Order or Invoice.
We get occasional walk-up customers and the way we are planning on handling them if they are paying with a CC is generating an invoice for a generic "Walk Up Customer" and applying the CC payment to that invoice.

In the interest of making this process slightly faster for the end user, I'd like to have a basic script that activates on a link or a button on their dashboard that automatically creates an invoice and fills in the fields for the customer, location, etc - then all they need to do is enter their line items, save, and process the payment. (We have barcodes enabled for them to enter line items)

I did a little research and found that the function below should perform what I need it to do, but I do not know how to build it to trigger on a link or button click.

```
...
var objRecord = record.transform({
    fromType: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
    fromId: xxxx,
    toType: record.Type.INVOICE,
    isDynamic: true,
});
...
```

If this is as simple as I'm hoping it is, I'd love some assistance!

I have seen plenty of examples on how to trigger a script like this on a record creation and etc., but not to do it manually via a link or a button.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this before, but in a simpler way:
You can navigate to a new invoice page with default values by using url parameters.
There's [an interesting post on Marty Zigman's site on this](https://blog.prolecto.com/2018/05/20/drive-values-to-netsuite-forms-and-other-url-tricks/)

In this scenario, you can create a link on your dashboard with the following url:
https://system.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/custinvc.nl?whence=&entity=YOURDEFAULTCUSTOMERID
and that's it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are set to have this functionality on the dashboard, you'll need two components.

1. Custom portlet that will have a field for selecting a customer and a Submit button
2. Suitelet that will redirect you to the transformed invoice

The portlet:

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.1
* @NScriptType Portlet
*/
define(['N/log', 'N/url', 'N/ui/serverWidget'],
/**
 * @param{log} log
 * @param{url} url
 * @param{serverWidget} serverWidget
 */
function (log, url, serverWidget) {
    /**
     * Defines the Portlet script trigger point.
     * @param {Object} params - The params parameter is a JavaScript object. It is automatically passed to the script entry
     *     point by NetSuite. The values for params are read-only.
     * @param {Portlet} params.portlet - The portlet object used for rendering
     * @param {string} params.column - Column index forthe portlet on the dashboard; left column (1), center column (2) or
     *     right column (3)
     * @param {string} params.entity - (For custom portlets only) references the customer ID for the selected customer
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    const render = (params) => {
        params.portlet.title = 'Invoice from Customer';
        params.portlet.addField({
            id:     'custpage_customer',
            type:   serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
            label:  'Customer',
            source: -2
        });
        let suiteletUrl = url.resolveScript({
            deploymentId:      'customdeploy_invoice_portlet',
            scriptId:          'customscript_invoice_portlet',
            returnExternalUrl: false
        });
        params.portlet.setSubmitButton({
            url:    suiteletUrl,
            label:  'Create Invoice',
            target: '_top'
        });
    }

    return {render}

});
```

portlet.addField will add our select field with internal id custpage_customer, the internal id of source for customer list is -2.
The suiteletUrl will be the internal id of your suitelet script and its deployment.
When you deploy the portlet, it will be of type Simple Form.

The suitelet:

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.1
* @NScriptType Suitelet
*/
define(['N/redirect'],
/**
 * @param{redirect} redirect
 */
(redirect) => {
    /**
     * Defines the Suitelet script trigger point.
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {ServerRequest} scriptContext.request - Incoming request
     * @param {ServerResponse} scriptContext.response - Suitelet response
     * @since 2015.2
     */
    const onRequest = (scriptContext) => {
        if (scriptContext.request.method == 'POST')
        {
            let customerId = scriptContext.request.parameters.custpage_customer;
            redirect.toRecordTransform({
                fromId:   customerId,
                fromType: record.Type.CUSTOMER,
                toType:   record.Type.INVOICE
            });
        }
    }

    return {onRequest}

});
```

The suitelet will just gather the value of your customer field (custpage_customer) from the parameters and redirects you to the Invoice using the redirect.toRecordTransform.